# Data truncation: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value

Tags: java, mysql

```
// my button
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {               
  String sorgu="UPDATE calisan SET CalisanAdi=? AND CalisanSoyadi=? AND kul_adi=? AND sifre=? WHERE idcalisan=? ";
  DBConnection.KullaniciGuncelle(calisan_ad.getText(), calisan_soyad.getText(),calisan_kul_adi.getText(), calisan_sifre.getText(), sorgu);
}
```

What's wrong? If I add column this show problems

> parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0)

```
public static void KullaniciGuncelle(String ad, String soyad, String kadi, String sifre,String sorgu){

connection();

try
{
    Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection(host, username , pass);
    PreparedStatement statement = (PreparedStatement) connect.prepareStatement(sorgu);

    statement.setString(1, ad);
    statement.setString(2, soyad);
    statement.setString(3, kadi);
    statement.setString(4, sifre);

    statement.executeUpdate();
    statement.close();
    connect.close();   
}
catch(SQLException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();  
}
```

Comment: `update table_name set col1='val1', col2='val2',... where col1='something'`

Comment: It's impossible to tell what's wrong here because we have no idea what's in your table or all those classes upon which you call `getText()`. Please clarify your question. You also have five bind parameters `?` in your query but only four parameters  plus the query string to the `DbConnection` method you are invoking.

Comment: if i use ' parameter value problem :S

Comment: what do you think this code? DBConnection here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only binding four parameters in your update method. But your query string contains five. Also, you're misusing `AND` in your query.

The query should be this, removing the extra `AND` items.

```
UPDATE calisan 
   SET CalisanAdi=?, CalisanSoyadi=?,
       kul_adi=?, sifre=?
WHERE idcalisan=? ";
```

Your update method needs an extra parameter bind for the fifth `?`. I guess `idcalisan` is an ID (even though I'm ignorant of Turkish, sorry) so I've suggested `setInt()`.

```
    statement.setString(1, ad);
    statement.setString(2, soyad);
    statement.setString(3, kadi);
    statement.setString(4, sifre);
    statement.setInt   (5, idcalisan)
```

Comment: if i use extra parameter, KullaniciGuncelle method need to new textbox.